# Accelerometer missing data and classification in WEKA

Tags: authentication, machine-learning, classification, weka, accelerometer

For activity recognition purpose, I have collected accelerometer and gyroscope data during walking activity from two different devices. I have the accelerometer data (x,y, and z) and gyroscope data (x,y, and z) from both devices and I'm trying to build my feature vector. An example of how my feature vector looks like is as follows (note that I have hundreds of readings for each coordinate: x, y and z):
[image]

My questions:

1. In some cases, I have fewer readings samples such in 1st_phone_Gyro and 2nd_Phone_Gyro What do I do with the empty spaces here? Should I put zeros knowing that WEKA complains if I have these empty cells. Would having zeros affect the classification?
2. Any suggestion what features can be extracted to improve the performance and what algorithm would give the best recognition result?

Answer (score 1):

There is not much noise in your data. Hence you can reasonably estimate missing values by [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). If the missing values are rare, you can remove these entries.

Since there is certain time dependance here, I guess [RNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network)s will give good accuracy. A special type of a RNN is a [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), which has abilities of remembering events from variable time periods.

You can also try "bundling" about 100 inputs to generate some useful input for training standard CNNs for classification.

Comment: Hi Meet, thanks for your answer and the recommendation of the algorithms, I will try them. Just to let you know, this just an example of how my data looks like. In reality, I have more than hundreds of readings for each coordinates (x,y,z).